# Integrating HTML and CSS with Kotlin and Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring-mvc, kotlin

I would like to add some html and css for my spring project. I am running gradle, and using Kotlin. My current tree directory is like so: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrL75.png) (I have not included gradle build files).

I am simply trying to print "Hello $name$" given some input at web address. This works. Here is GreetingController.kt :

```
@RestController
    class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
         fun greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") name: String, model: Model) {
         model.addAttribute("name", name);
         return "greeting";
    }
}
```

My gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2' // Required for Kotlin integration
ext.spring_boot_version = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
    dependencies {
        classpath "se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" // Required for Kotlin integration
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version"
     }
}

apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'kotlin' // Required for Kotlin integration
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'

jar {
    baseName = 'webapp'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" // Required for Kotlin integration
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testCompile 'junit:junit'
}

task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
    push = false
    applicationName = jar.baseName
    dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from jar
            into stageDir
        }
    }
} 

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.5'
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.tunnll.spring.webapp.Application'
}
```

Additionally, my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: The website is running locally, so I cannot provide a link.
At present, it prints "greeting" which is what I am returning in the GreetingController. However, I would like it to show up as "Hello World", which is what would be produced by the html file. It may be an issue that the html file is not connected to the application. I'm not certain. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your website link points to `localhost`.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Had forgotten it is only locally available. I added a description of what appears. It's very minimalistic, so it shouldn't be a problem on that end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the @RestController when I should have used only @Controller. 
Additionally, the html file should have been located in the resources/templates directory.